# Can I use links in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have manifest.json containing this:

```
{
    "name": "Extension name",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "description",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.google.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
                "main.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

How to use:

```
"js": [
         "jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
         "main.js"
      ]
```

With links?
If I want to use my file that I update online every time as:

```
"js": [
         "jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
         "https://mywebsite.com/scripts/main.js"
      ]
```

Comment: This seems like a non-question. You can easily check if the manifest loads, or if it doesn't. That should answer your question.

Comment: I did but nothing happens and I have no errors, nothing...